# How to show version in jshell

Tags: java, jshell

On startup jshell shows the version:

```
Welcome to JShell -- Version 14.0.1
```

But is there a way to retrieve the version programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about executing `Runtime.version()`?

[image]

Comment: System.out.println(Runtime.version());

Comment: @DhiogoBoza I hope that's just to keep a note for text reference from the image.

Comment: Exactly! It's only to add an option to copy. Thanks for your response, it helped me.